# Passing one Method Parameters, To another method - c#

Tags: c#, methods, rename

Is it possible to take parameters from one method to another?

Basiclly what I want to do is rename a method (in my case is The - `.WriteLine()` Method), Is there any way of creating a method with the name I want and have it take the parameters of another method like so:

```
void Func(Take The parametes of The .WriteLine method) //This is the rename of the method
{
   Console.WriteLine(place them here);
}
```

Basiclly I want to rename a method.

Comment: There is no syntactic sugar for the parameters. You'd have to declare them yourself. Note that there are several overloads of `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Are you trying to create an abstraction for the Console.WriteLine method? (So you can redirect where you want it to go when you want to.)  I ask, because there might be an easier way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: What's the reason for this? Might give us a clue as to how best to advise

Comment: @Charleh Im just doing a Coco Jumbo "Skin", i want every basic command or data type to have either coco or jumbo in them. So im "renaming" them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you want to do is pass an object to `Func` which should be passed on to the `WriteLine` method.

```
void Func(string SomeParameter) //This is the rename of the method     
{
   Console.WriteLine(SomeParameter);
}
```

`SomeParameter` will be passed to the `Func` method which calls `Console.WriteLine`. Use this function as :

```
Func("Hello World");
```

This should print the text "Hello World" on the output screen.

Comment: Yes. `SomeParameter` is a variable, a string in this case. It can accept variables of other data types also (int, decimal, char etc), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx